# Resize ImageView (Image filling its bounds) while retaining UIImage aspect ratio

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

How can I resize a UIImageView so that its height (width is always equal to the screen's portrait mode width) is proportion to the aspect ratio of the UIImage that it is showing? To better visualize what I mean, take for example the BuzzArt app.

When the image is longer (rectangular), the UIImageView adjusts..see..it becomes LONGER 
[image]

When the UiImage is SQUARE, the UIImageView adjusts too..see..it becomes SHORTER
[image]

I am sorry if I can't describe it perfectly but I hope the screenshots above can help.

How can I do the same in Swift?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

First we need to get the width of the screen:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
```

Next we get the image and create an image view with this image. Here I assume you have a `y` for the y origin point of the image view (the y coordinate of the top left corner of the image view) and also a `height` for the height of the image view, i.e. the maximum height of the image. The 0 before `y` indicates that the image view is all the way to the left edge of the screen:

```
let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "yourImageName")!
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,y,screenWidth,height)
```

We next need to ensure that the image is adjusted appropriately with its aspect ratio kept intact. We need to use a different `contentMode` depending on whether it is a portrait or landscape image:

```
if image.size.height > image.size.width {
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill  // Portrait
} else {
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit  // Landscape
}
```

Final step is to add the view:

```
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

n.b. Although this doesn't look to be the case for your app, I've found one bug that causes the image to move slightly, that is if the `height` of your `imageView` is less than `screenWidth`.

In full:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width

let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "yourImageName")!
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,y,screenWidth,height)

if image.size.height > image.size.width {
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill  // Portrait
} else {
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit  // Landscape
}

view.addSubview(imageView)
```